# Issue with "callback" action with parameters in Flutterflow

Tags: flutterflow

I was trying to use the new Callback Action and pass some action parameters and ran into this issue.

I have a custom dialog that I wanted to use before submitting data to backend. Without the modal I was successfully submitting the data to the backend and everything worked fine. With the modal when I want to pass action parameters the Image List array is not getting passed.

For the button that directly sits on the UI and does the operation, this is what the Backend call looks like for Image:

[image: Image-1]

But when I try to recreate this action for the callback, this is what it looks like. As soon as I select the Value Source as "Uploaded Photo/Video, I do not get the option to specify which "uploaded file URL" I want to send:

[image: Image-2]

Any idea why this might be happening?